# fileSystem.chooseEntry from package:chrome/app.dart generates runtime error

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app

Has anyone successfully used any fileSystem calls in package:chrome/app.dart? (This is the Chrome API package for Google Dart.)

Here's my code:

```dart
import 'package:chrome/app.dart';

void main() {
    fileSystem.chooseEntry();
}
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
name: ChooseEntry
description: A sample chrome packaged application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  chrome: any
  meta: any
```

The other files were generated automatically by the Dart Editor and remain untouched by me.

The error I get from Dartium is:

```
Breaking on exception: 'package:chrome/src/common.dart': malformed type: line 72 pos 29: type 'js.Callback' is not loaded
```

When I compile to JS and run in Dartium or Chrome, I get this error:

```
Uncaught RuntimeError: Error: Cannot resolve 'Callback'.
```

So, my question is whether anyone has successfully used the chooseEntry API, or any API in fileSystem and, if so, what about what I did needs to be fixed. My guess is that I'm missing a package, but I can't identify what it might be.

I did add package "js" to pubspec.yaml, with no effect. I also tried making copies of all the packages, in case Dartium or Chrome didn't handle the symlinks correctly, and that didn't help either. (I doubt that that's the problem, as it found the code for fileSystem.chooseEntry just fine.)

I'm using:

Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30798 (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.0.0.10_r30798

Comment: https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/blob/master/lib/src/common.dart#L72 appears to be the line in question. Perhaps that will help?

Comment: I had that from the stack trace. My question is where the Callback class is defined... what package do I have to include? I tried all of the packages that start with "js", to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chrome` package appears not to be maintained anymore, consider using `chrome_gen` instead by replacing `chrome` with `chrome_gen` in pubspec.yaml and by editing the import statement like this:

```
import 'package:chrome_gen/chrome_app.dart';

main() {
  fileSystem.chooseEntry();
}
```

The difference between these two packages is that wrappers are hand-written in `chrome` and autogenerated in `chrome_gen` from the json and idl files from Chrome.

*Links:*

[Pub Package: chrome_gen](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome_gen)

[Mailing List: What is the difference between chrome and chrome_gen ?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/X5Rfx-F_Iz8/MBwJJHLrugMJ)